# auto deducted type from sizeof differs between Visual Studio C++ and GCC

Tags: c++, sizeof, auto

I am a little lost here.

In my code I need to have an `unsigned int` as a reference for a call to an Rfc function by SAP Netweaver, the size of the buffer I give to the function.

In my VS environment, I program this:

```
auto buffer_length = sizeof(buffer);
auto rc = RfcCall...(..., &buffer_length, ...)
```

This compiles fine and hovering over `buffer_length" it shows, that it is indeed an unsigned int.

The exact same code, compiled with GCC 4.8.5 throws a compiler error - turns out that my variable is of type int there.

But why? And what can I do to prevent this? 
I thought there are standards to adhere to... :(

Comment: [Can't reproduce GCC 4.8.5 giving `int`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EC1n9O). The actual type, `std::size_t`, isn't guaranteed to be any particular type, either. Being `unsigned int` is not something you should rely on.

Comment: And on 64bits machines, it's probably not an `unsigned int` on both platforms.

Comment: try recieving a `std::size_t` inside your function

Comment: There is nothing to stop you coding `auto buffer_length = (unsigned int) sizeof (buffer);`

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from doing the audacious: `unsigned int buffer_length = (unsigned int) sizeof(buffer);`

Comment: or even the spectacular `std::uint32_t buffer_length = static_cast<std::uint32_t>(sizeof(buffer));` because int has a minimum per the standard, but the actual size is implementation defined.

Comment: @Tzalumen But my buffer_length is 4294967300 bytes, and YOU BROKE MY CODE! My sizeof(unsigned int) is 8.

Comment: That's a big buffer. So you'll need a std::uint64_t. The key here is that int has a defined minimum, but an implementation defined maximum. if your sizeof(unsigned int) is 8, your unsigned int is implemented as an unsigned long.

Comment: @phonetagger Anyway, the how and the why is covered in my answer with more detail.

Comment: @Tzalumen Yes, 4294967300 bytes would be a really big buffer, if I actually had one that big. I just picked an example 8 bytes bigger than 2^32 so I could say you broke my code.

Comment: Show the actual, exact, error. Copy & paste it. Don't just tell us about it. Better yet, accompany it with a [MCVE]. (After 9 years and 7k rep you should know this by now!)

Answer (score 2):

According to §18.2p6 [support.types]:

> The type `size_t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.

And §5.3.3p6 [expr.sizeof]:

> The result of `sizeof` and `sizeof...` is a constant of type `std::size_t`.

So, `sizeof(buffer)` is an *unsigned* integer type, by the standard. Either there is a bug in GCC (Which is unlikely, as [`std::size_t` is `unsigned long`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NaAnzp)) or your error is not where you think it is.

Comment: Which revision of the standard is this? ISO/IEC 14882:1998(E) doesn't have a §18.2p6

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing the ISO standard, cppreference gives:

> sizeof() returns a value of std::size_t, which is defined, by the standard as
>
> `typedef /*implementation-defined*/ size_t;`

The only guarantee you have is that

> std::size_t can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array).

This holds at least up to C++11, ISO C++ defers the definition of std::size_t to ISO C, which in turn defers it to the compiler. I have Visual Studio 2015, so it lives in vcruntime.h, where the definition is

```
#ifdef _WIN64
    typedef unsigned __int64 size_t;
...
#else
    typedef unsigned int     size_t;
```

C++11 added fixed width integer types, such as `std::uint64_t`, which is guaranteed to be a 64-bit unsigned integer. You can then use `static_cast<std::uint64_t>(sizeof(buffer))` to convert it before assignment.

Comment: @Zordid In a more general sense, while auto is convenient, it's best used when you know *explicitly* what the type will be. I use it almost exclusively in ranged-for loops.

Comment: It's also guaranteed to be unsigned. The text you quote doesn't appear in the current standard,  it would be good to specify exactly which document you quote when attempting to quote the standard.

Comment: I was pulling from the current data on cppreference.com. Maybe the text is changed for one of the newer C++ revisions, such as C++20?

Comment: cppreference isn't the ISO standard.

Comment: Yes, and ISO/IEC 14882:1998(E) doesn't have an §18.2p6, your point?

Comment: I never said it was ... you could consider editing your answer to link to the source of your quotes

Comment: Well, I looked, and cppreference is not wrong, the typedef for size_t lives in the C compiler. For Visual Studio 2015 at least, it's defined in vcruntime.h